# Laravel nested eager loading error when showing it to output

Tags: php, laravel, eager-loading

I have nested looping view on laravel and i am having problem when i try to show the list of my items.

Here is the code where i have the error

```
     @foreach($project->codes->items as $item)
    <tr>

        <td>{!! $item->item !!}</td>
    </tr>
     @endforeach
```

and it produces this error.

```
Cannot access protected property Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$items
```

I have setup the models for project, code and items as.

Project Model

```
class Project extends Model
{

public $table = 'projects';

public function codes() {

    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Code');
  }
}
```

Code Model

```
public function code() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Project');
}

public function items() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Item');
}
```

item model

```
public function  item() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Code');
}
```

And here's how i implement it on the controller

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $this->projectRepository->pushCriteria(new  RequestCriteria($request));
    $projects = $this->projectRepository->with('codes.items')->all();

    return view('projects.index')
        ->with('projects', $projects);
}
```

I have run the code on artisan tinker and it shows the correct data. But not loading on the output php.
Thank You for your support.

Answer (score -1):

Please share the output

i think it should be like this

```
 @foreach($project->codes as $code)
    @foreach($code->items as $it)
   <tr>

      <td>{!! $it->item !!}</td>
   </tr>
   @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Did this work for you? if yes please mark the question as answered